# Include class in controller Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am learning Zend Framework 2 and i am looking for a way to include [PHP mobile detect script](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/). I dont know where to place the file, how to properly include it in controller and how to use it on page?

Answer (score 1):

You have this module https://github.com/neilime/zf2-mobile-detect (Link from https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect#projects-that-are-using-the-class)

To install this module, just follow instructions :

- https://github.com/neilime/zf2-mobile-detect#installation

To use it in a controller (Ref to the documentation)

```
$mobileDetect = $this->mobileDetect(); //Retrieve "\Mobile_Detect" object
$mobileDetect->isMobile();

$mobileDetect = $this->mobileDetect(
    \Zend\Http\Headers::fromString('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Desire HD Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19')
); //Retrieve "\Mobile_Detect" object with arbitrary http headers
$mobileDetect->isAndroidOS();
```

ps: Don't forget to enable it into your ***application.config.php***